# Expresión Regular que no permita espacios al final

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

Estoy trabajando con esta expresión `/^([a-zA-Z0-9]){1,16}$/` la cual me valida un campo que solo le pueden ingresar alfanuméricos de longitud máxima de 16 caracteres, pero necesito adicionarle que no permita espacios al final.

He probado agregando al final `[:space:]` ó `\s` y no me funciona.

Quien me puede orientar.

Saludos cordiales

Comment: alternativamente podes descartar espacios con [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

Comment: Tu expresión actual no permite espacios, ni al final, ni en medio. Ten cuidado, tan poco permites ñ ni Ñ. ¿Tu pregunta es como poder tener espacions en medio pero no al final?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu expresión regular es correcta. Simplemente pásale la opción `ng-trim="false"` a tu input. Por ejemplo:

`<input type="text" ng-model="model" id="input" name="input" ng-pattern="/^([a-zA-Z0-9]){1,16}$/" ng-trim="false" />`

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/9kNnYIGOEg5jAoIIfPNN?p=preview)**

Según la [documentación](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D):

> **ngTrim** (optional)
>
> If set to false Angular will not automatically trim the input. This parameter is ignored for input[type=password] controls, which
>   will never trim the input.
>
> (default: true)

Comment: perfecto así funcionó. Muchas gracias a todos por sus aportes.

Answer (score 2):

Tal como está planteado no permite espacios, ni antes ni entre ni después. Usar la plantilla siguiente para probar las regexp

```js
document.getElementById('dale').onclick = (ev) => {
  let exp = document.getElementById('laExpresion').value;
  let re = new RegExp(exp);
  console.log("/" + exp + "/", re.test(document.getElementById('elTexto').value));
}
```

```html
Expresión: <input type="text" id="laExpresion" value="^([a-zA-Z0-9]){1,16}$" /><br />
Texto: <input type="text" id="elTexto" />
<button id="dale">validar</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es la misma expresión que estoy usando, lo raro es que a mí cuando hago la validación con espacios al final se me comporta como si el resultado fuera "true"

Comment: Este desarrollo usa angular v1.6.1, sera por la versión?

Comment: habría que ver código en contexto, si hay algún otro filtro o modificador del valor a validar. Fijate este hilo a ver si te da pistas https://stackoverflow.com/a/39122248/1423096

Comment: Muchas gracias @alo Malbarez

Answer (score 1):

has probado de la siguiente manera?

`/([a-zA-Z0-9\s]){1,15}[^\s]/`

Ya que validar espacios es con `\s` por lo tanto descartar espacios sería con `\S` o `[^\s]`

Espero te sirva!

Saludos

Comment: No funciona con lo que me sugieres. Gracias por responder.

Comment: para mas "completitud" habría que agregar los "espacios invisibles" como hace el [polyfill de trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim#Polyfill)

Comment: Esto validaría `ABCDE@`, que no es correcto

Answer (score 0):

También podrías buscar espacios al inicio y al final y después decidir qué hacer con ellos

`^\s+|\s+$`

Comment: La expresión que tengo ya me valida los espacios al inicio /^([a-zA-Z0-9]){1,16}$/  y permite alfanuméricos de la longitud que requiero, solo que me esta permitiendo pasar espacios al final y es lo que necesito restringir.

Answer (score 0):

Bajo el supuesto de mi pregunta, esto podría valerte:

```
^([a-zñA-ZÑ0-9\s]){0,15}[a-zñA-ZÑ0-9]$
```

Puedes usar una página para probar expresiones regulares para ir consruyendola, como esta https://regex101.com/

Comment: @javrd no me funciona me permite espacios al final, es mas me habilita para poner espacio estre caracteres :(

Comment: @HectorEcheverri a eso me refería justamente con ["Bajo el supuesto de mi pregunta"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/206802/expresi%C3%B3n-regular-que-no-permita-espacios-al-final/206837#comment386144_206802). Como te he dicho ahi, tu expresión ya controla que no se puedan poner espacios al final. Quizá el problema este en otra parte de tu código...

Answer (score -1):

Si necesitas utilizar solo caracteres numéricos puedes hacer lo siguiente `oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')"` tu html debería quedar de la siguente maner, y no tendrías que colocarlo en el js.

```
<input type="text" id="identification" class="input_global"
               placeholder="IDENTIFICACIÓN"
               maxlength="20" minlength="6"
               oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')" >
```

Comment: Hola LUIS, gracias por tu colaboración, antes de contestar, es importante leer bien la pregunta y los comentarios de esta y las respuestas que pueda haber, la pregunta dice claramente, "caracteres alfanuméricos" por lo que tu respuesta es incorrecta, te sugiero que o bien la edites y adaptes a la consigna, o la elimines para evitar recibir votos negativos... si hubiese leído bien, sabrías que la pregunta fue formulada hace cuatro años..

Answer (score -2):

Podés probar `/[\w]+[^\s]$/`:

- `\w` Cualquier caracter entre `0-9`, `a-z` y `A-Z`
- `+` Cualquier cantidad de veces
- `[^\s]$` Que no termine en espacio

Comment: Esto validaría `ABCDE@`, que no es correcto